Best pl/sql strategy to return a single output row of a concatenated list within a list
I have the following data sample below.
User      Levl        Clan            Skills          WpnCode
Sam       100         Daredevil       Beginner       
Sam       100         Daredevil       Archery         Archblst
Sam       100         Daredevil       Archery         Archaccy
Sam       100         Daredevil       Powershot       Cannon
Sam       100         Daredevil       Powershot       Rifle
Sam       125         Bluesy          Beginner        Rod
Sam       125         Bluesy          Archery         Greenarch
Sam       125         Bluesy          Archery         Bluearch
Sam       125         Bluesy          Powershot       Torch
Sam       125         Bluesy          Powershot       Knife
Sam       150         Stargaze        Beginner        Stick
Sam       150         Stargaze        Powershot       Magnum
Sam       150         Stargaze        Powershot       Pistol

UPDATE: Sorry, the sample data is not one table, here's the query to generate the sample data:
4/6: Figured out what's wrong with my pl/sql so just fixed it instead - thanks to both who have responded +1! Picking little foot since it made me think of other ways
select   b.username       User,                  
         b.Level          Levl,                        
         b.Club           Clan,
         a.Skills,                                     
         a.Weapons        WpnCode        
 from detl a,prof b
 where a.usercode = b.username     
 and a.tagcde = b.tagid                             
 and b.username = '&&User'; --Sam

Desired outputs:
varProf = Daredevil-Archblst,ArchAccy[Cannon,Rifle]
varProf2 = Bluesy-Greenarch,Bluearch[Torch,Knife],Stargaze[Magnum,Pistol]

First attempt for returning only varProf:
 DECLARE
    varProf VARCHAR2(500) := '';
 BEGIN
    SELECT
        LISTAGG(
            CASE 
                WHEN PSWpn = 'Beginner' THEN Clan
                ELSE Clan || '[' || WpnList || ']'
            END,
            '-'
        ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Levl) INTO varProf
    FROM (
        SELECT = Clan, PSWpn, Levl,
            LISTAGG(WpnCode, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY WpnCode) AS WpnList
        FROM (
            SELECT
                Club AS Clan,
                CASE WHEN Skills = 'Powershot' THEN 'Powershot' ELSE 'Beginner' END AS PSWpn,
                Level AS Levl,
                Weapons AS WpnCode
            FROM
                -- my joins are here
            WHERE
                -- my conditions and prompts are here
        )
        GROUP BY Clan, PSWpn, Levl
    );

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('varProf = ' ||varProf);
 END;

It wasn't right since it appending (-) the Clan instead of the Archery Skill.
So I tried using another strategy by just looping the records:
 DECLARE
  varProf VARCHAR2(500) := '';
  varProf2 VARCHAR2(500) := '';
 BEGIN
  FOR rec IN (
    SELECT Club AS Clan, Weapons AS WpnCode, Level AS Levl, Skills 
    FROM
        -- my tables
    WHERE
        -- my conditions 
   ) LOOP
    IF rec.Levl = 1 THEN
        IF varProf IS NULL OR varProf = '' THEN
           varProf := rec.Clan || '-' || rec.WpnCode;
        ELSE
            varProf := varProf || ',' || rec.Clan || '-' || rec.WpnCode;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        IF varProf2 IS NULL OR varProf2 = '' THEN
           varProf2 := rec.Clan || '-' || rec.WpnCode;
        ELSE
            varProf2 := varProf2 || ', ' || rec.Clan || '-' || rec.WpnCode;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END LOOP;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('varProf = ' || varProf);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('varProf2 = ' || varProf2);
END;

While it did append the Skills, I did not include the listagg for the WpnCode... is there a better strategy to have the desired outputs that I want?
Basically the sample data is for one user and his profiles (I have the condition to prompt for the username in the where clause). But anyway, I want to return their 100 level Clan name.  Followed by a "-" to append their Archery Weapons (separated by "," if multiple) which is identified by Skills = Archery.  And finally append an enclosed [ ] which inside is the list of Powershot Weapons/WpnCode, separated by comma if multiple WpnCodes, and this is identified by Skills = Powershot.
Then, I also want to display Clan name(s), that are not level 100 (Levl <> 100). Using the same logic above, but the major difference is that they can have multiple over 100lv Clans, which I want them distinctly listed out as well (no dupes), separated by comma.
Here's the desired outputs once again:
varProf = Daredevil-Archblst,ArchAccy[Cannon,Rifle]
varProf2 = Bluesy-Greenarch,Bluearch[Torch,Knife],Stargaze[Magnum,Pistol]


Does it have to be PL/SQL? If so, split the following query in two separate SELECTs.
SQL> select a.clan ||'-'||
  2         listagg(distinct b.wpncode, ',') ||'[' ||
  3         listagg(distinct c.wpncode, ',') ||']' as result
  4  from test a left join test b on a.clan = b.clan and b.skills = 'Archery'
  5              left join test c on c.clan = a.clan and c.skills = 'Powershot'
  6  where a.clan = '&&par_clan'
  7    and a.skills = 'Beginner'
  8  group by a.clan
  9  union all
 10  select listagg(result, ',')
 11  from (
 12    -- same query as above, with minor changes in WHERE clause
 13    select a.clan ||'-'||
 14           listagg(distinct b.wpncode, ',') ||'[' ||
 15           listagg(distinct c.wpncode, ',') ||']' as result
 16    from test a left join test b on a.clan = b.clan and b.skills = 'Archery'
 17                left join test c on c.clan = a.clan and c.skills = 'Powershot'
 18    where a.clan <> '&&par_clan'
 19      and a.skills <> 'Beginner'
 20    group by a.clan
 21    -- end of same query
 22    );
Enter value for par_clan: Daredevil

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Daredevil-Archaccy,Archblst[Cannon,Rifle]
Bluesy-Bluearch,Greenarch[Knife,Torch],Stargaze-[Magnum,Pistol]

SQL>


It doesn't matter. Either use that query (that produces "sample data") as a view, or a CTE.

you can try the below
select distinct replace(replace(valprof, ',,', ''), ' ', '') valprof
 from (select (b.Club || '-') ||
           LISTAGG(decode(a.skills, 'Powershot', ',', a.weapons), ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER By a.Weapons) OVER(PARTITION BY b.lvl, b.club) || '[' || LISTAGG(decode(a.skills, 'Powershot', a.weapons, ','), ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER By a.Weapons) OVER(PARTITION BY b.lvl, b.club) || ']' valprof
      from detl a, prof b
     where a.usercode = b.username
       and a.tagcde = b.tagid
       and b.username = '&&User'
       and a.skills <> 'Beginner'
    
    )

